# Low-Rank Approximation using Frobenious Norm Tolerance

Tags: algorithm, matlab, svd, image-compression

I would love some help with an algorithm I've working on. My specific problem is in the **while** loop of the algorithm.

What I want the algorithm to do is to sequentially add a singular value in **Sk**(until the desired **TOL** is achieved) in the diagonal while making the rest of the matrix 0. The desired goal is to do this to greyscale images.

I can only get 2x2 cycles.

here is the code:

```
A    = rand(5)*30;
[M N]   = size(A);
[U S V] = svds(A);
% r  = rank(A);
Sn = S(1,1);
Sk   = blkdiag(Sn,zeros(N-1));
Ak   = U*Sk*V;
X    = A - Ak;
F    = norm(X,'fro');
tol  = 10;


i = 2;

while F > tol
    Snk  = S(i,i);
    Snew = diag([Sn;Snk]);
    Sk   = blkdiag(Snew,zeros(N-2));
    Ak   = U*Sk*V';
    F    = norm(A-Ak,'fro');
    i    = i + 1;
end
```